# Get local IP of a machine connected to a network in WEB API

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

i am trying to get Local Ip of machine connected to an network in ASP.Net WEB API.Is There Any way of doing this?

Comment: What do you mean by the "local IP?" Are you referring to it's private, NATed IPv4 address?

Comment: yes the one which local network assign to my machine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
You can get local IP of machine following way.Thanks

    private string LocalIPAddress()
       {
            IPHostEntry host;
            string localIP = "";
            host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
            foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
            {
                if (ip.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    localIP = ip.ToString();
                }
            }
            return localIP;
        }
```

Comment: Glad to help you ! Cheers